Where are the application's shared libraries located?
I used frida to hook the loadLibrary function and get the name of the so file that the application is loading, but I can't find the file under /data/app/. Where is it located?

For APK files built with a recent build system and config the shared libraries (.so files) are never extracted from APK.
Instead they are directly mapped into memory from within the APK file in which they are saved uncompressed and aligned to 4K boundaries.
Not sure which property marks the APK not to extract the shared libraries (or may be this is the default setting on recent Android versions?). On older Android versions the entry android:extractNativeLibs=false in AndroidManifest.xml told Android not to extract the shared library files upon installation.

Thank you. It's clear now.

so file I was looking for were in split_config.arm64_v8a.apk.
